# WebStorm not able to change default mocha reporter

Tags: webstorm

I am passing in `--reporter Mochawesome` in 'Edit Configuration'.

But WebStorm console shows both the reporters.

`--reporter mochawesome` as well as

`--reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js`

No mochawesome report is created.

How to generate Mochawesome reports using WebStorm?

[image: Nodejs run configuration]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebStorm uses its own reporter to represent test results as a tree view with filters/navigation etc. So you can't use other reporters when using Mocha integration. If you prefer getting output produced by other reporters instead, you have to run Mocha with Node.js run configuration

Comment: Thank you. How Do I run Mocha with Node.js configuration? I tried unchecking Node.js option in plugin. If I do that, 'Edit Configuration' does not show Mocha option.

Comment: you need creating Node.js run configuration, not disabling a plugin (what a strange idea, btw - disabling a plugin to run smth).

Comment: In Node.js run configuration, specify `node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha` as Javscript file, pass `--reporter Mochawesome /path/to/your/spec` as Application parameters

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above Node.js run configuration. It still do not get my report. I am still seeing node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --ui tdd --reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your run configuration.

Comment: Added screenshot in the main question section above (Cannot add images in comments).

Comment: are you sure that you start a Node.js configuration and not your mocha one? from the command line (`--ui tdd --reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-‌​intellij/lib/mochaIn‌​tellijReporter.js`) it is clear that mocha run configuration is run

Comment: I am using mochawesome report for mocha test suite. /usr/local/bin/node /Users/x/Documents/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --reporter mochawesome --ui bdd --reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js /Users/x/Documents/Test.js

Comment: sorry, don't understand. why do you pass `--reporter /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-‌​intellij/lib/mochaIn‌​tellijReporter.js` to mocha in your Node.js run configuration? what for?

Comment: I don't pass --reporter mocha‌​In‌​tellijReporter.j‌​s to mocha. I run my mocha test suite using Mocha run configuration. mocha‌​In‌​tellijReporter.j‌​s is being set by webstorm as the default reporter and mochawesome reports are not created.

Comment: rrrrr... as I have already wrote, you can't use reporters other than `mocha‌​In‌​tellijReporter` when using *Mocha* run configuration. If you like to use a different reporter, use *Node.js* run configuration

Comment: many many thanks for your patience!! I can now generate mochawesome reports for mocha test suite via Node.js configuration.